# How to see an edge length in 3Ds Max

Tags: 3d, polygon, 3dsmax, maxscript

I have a 3Ds Max question.

I created a Box and transformed it to Editable Poly.
Then I use Extrude to make walls.
To check size of some walls I need to see its Edge length (Edge selection).

Tools->Measure distance is not working for Edge.
Utilities->Measure also is not working for Edge.

I checked all menu items and did not found how to see an Edge length.
Further, I used google and found only one advice: "DiMaster" script.

So, 3Ds Max does not have native instrument to show an Edge length?
How to see an Edge length?

Answer (score 1):

You have to get two vertex of edge, and get distance between this two points

```
twopoints = polyOp.getEdgeVerts $ 1
d = distance $.verts[twopoints[1]].pos $.verts[twopoints[2]].pos
messagebox (d as string)
```